# Quais palavras de origem africana existem no português brasileiro que não existem no português de Portugal?

Tags: estrangeirismos

É sabido que o português brasileiro sofre várias influências de dialetos africanos. Quais são as palavras que possuem essas origens?

Adicionalmente, quais são sinônimos presentes no português de Portugal?

---

**In English**

It is known that the Brazilian Portuguese has undergone several African dialects influences. What are these words that have these sources?

In addition, what are synonymous present in the Portuguese of Portugal for them?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: one would need a book to answer it.

Comment: Would you be happy with just receiving some examples? Then we can ask instead "what are some examples of", and in my opinion it'd not be excessively broad.

Comment: Related http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-influence-of-tupi-guarani-in-Brazilian-Portuguese

Comment: What about tags listing the words in the Wiki?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez It's too many words IMO, even for a tag wiki.

Comment: Well, I restricted the scope to try to reopen the question.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez it's hard to say when a question is broad, but not enough to be closed as _too broad_. This question's scope has been restricted after the edit, but IMHO it is still too broad.

Comment: @gmauch I'm really trying to save the question, but I confess that I'm lacking of options.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez explaining with a comparison: to me, a too-broad question would be `what names are used in Brasil that are not used in Portugal?`, and its scope could be reduced to an acceptable size by changing it to `what are some examples of names used in Brasil that are not used in Portugal?`. A complete answer to the broad version would have **hundreds** of names... (That is not to say that a question cannot have a *lot* of possible answers! [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) has **9** answers with more than 100 upvotes.)

Comment: But can we just try to answer? I think in the research value that this can have.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure this site encourages questions asking for lists. Other SE sites do not. Anyway, I going to cite just a few and then learn if this type of question is accepted here. In pt-BR there are some words I never heard in pt-PT:

- bunda (buttocks, in English) In Portugal they call it... well, you know.
- quitute (a delicacy, in English). The Portuguese say "uma iguaria".
- fofoca (gossip, in English) The Portuguese call it "mexerico".

Edit: I must admit I forgot to write about their etymology.  Caqui sounds very much like a Native-American word, but I would have to check that.

Edit 2: Since the original question has been rephrased and asks for words brought from African dialects only, I'm changing my answer.

Comment: What do you suggest? A tag, maybe?

Comment: We say "sotaque" in Portugal; "acento" is the graphical mark. And the languages are pt-BR and pt-PT.

Comment: -1: none of those words are tupi-guarani or african in origin.

Comment: @ANeves  I never heard anyone say "sotaque" in Portugal.  "acento" is what I've heard.  Both on the islands and in the continent.  As for the abbreviations, I'll fix that, thank you.

Comment: @Centaurus what? Everybody says "sotaque" like "tens um sotaque engraçado". I had never heard "acento" in this sense...

Comment: caqui is from Japanese _kaki_.

Comment: @Centaurus in my experience, the only alternative in Portugal to "sotaque" is "pronúncia". (Cue "Pronúncia do Norte"...)

Comment: I restricted the question scope to try a reopening. Can you please update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @ANeves I don't live in Portugal, I live in Brazil.  My experience in Portugal, where I have citizenship and often visit, is different from yours, though.

Comment: @Earthliŋ - caqui (the fruit, often also called cáqui in Southern Brazil) is from Japanese; cáqui (the colour) is from Persian.